# How to Retrieve BLOB Data In Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I want to retrieve BLOB data from database table to Display Image Item called P4_COMPANY_LOGO

I have selected the source for Display image item as **SQL Query (Return Single Value):**

```
select company_logo from companies where company_id=10;
```

But when I run the page it immediately return this Error:

```
P4_COMPANY_LOGO has to have a valid BLOB column as source.
```

**Help Please!..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have the item properties quite right.  This would work:

[image]